# How to record blazemeter script for 3 different scenarios and run in JMeter for 3 different users

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, blazemeter

I am using JMeter for Load and Performance testing. I have 3 scenarios to test as follows;

Importing Files
Downloading Reports
Submitting Form

I have recorded this script with one user.
Now I want to run these three scenarios at a same time with 3 threads for one scenario.
I can add 3 as a value in threads but how to make all the three action running at a time?
Any suggestions?

Is this the way
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Each JMeter thread (virtual user) executes [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down (or  according to [logic controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers)). It means that if you add 3 users - they will execute first Importing Files then Downloading Reports then Submitting Form.
2. Normally different groups of business users should go to separate [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) so you can split these recorded scenarios into 3 Thread Groups and set how many users you want to execute each of them
3. If you need to run 3 requests with 3 users at exactly the same moment - take a look at [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer)
4. If you need to run 3 requests with 1 user at exactly the same moment - take a look at [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-controller)

Comment: Please check screenshot. is that what you said for point 2?